What is the problem with my drone?
I am a newbie regarding drones. I created a drone using the following tutorial - drone link
The tutorial is about making a wall climbing drone but I ignored the climbing part of the drone. The drone is controlled using a mobile application. The parts that I used for the drone are - Node MCU ESP8266,mpu6050,TP4056 - Battery Charging/Protection Module (Micro USB), DC 3.7V 716 7x16mm Micro Coreless Motor(4 units), SI2302 Mosfet – N Channel – 2.2A – SOT-23(4 units), 1 Kilo Ohm Resistors(4 units), 500 mAh 3.7V single cell Rechargeable LiPo Battery,Q100 Brushed Quad-copter Frame, a small switch. The weight of the whole drone after assembling is just 50gram(accurate). The drone connects to the mobile application but after giving full power through the app the drone motors spin at high speed but it doesn't lift up from the ground. It may move a little bit along ground but doesn't lift up. The battery is a normal battery, I have heard that drones need to have batteries with something called C rating. But the battery specified in the tutorial was just a 3.7v lipo battery. So can you help me by figuring out the real problem. What I have to do to make the drone actually fly?

50g is quite heavy for brushed motors, so it may be that the props aren't making enough thrust. Are the props, motors and weight all the same as the tutorial? Are the props the right way up (curved side up)? Are the props all blowing the right way?
If your battery C rating was too low, the motors would slow down and stop after a few seconds, so I don't think it's that.
